# Return a string by reference from tbl_df of numerics in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tibble

I have a tbl_df (tibble) named 'control.scores' that has a column called "Overall", which is some value between 1.00 and 4.00.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 8
      group   GOV  CORC  TMSC     AUDIT   PPS     TRAIN  Overall
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Group4  0.82   0.2 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.261667
2 Group5  0.82   0.0 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.061667
```

I also have a another tbl_df, called 'control.rating.tbl' constructed:

```
# create a reference table of control ratings and numeric ranges
control.ref.tbl <- tribble(
  ~RATING, ~MIN, ~MAX,
  "Ineffective", 3.500, 4.00,
  "Marginally Effective",2.500 ,3.499,
  "Generally Effective", 1.500 ,2.499,
  "Highly Effective", 1.00, 1.499
)
```

How can I append one more column to 'control.scores' that uses the value in Overall and checks its position between the MIN and MAX range of 'control.rating.tbl' and return the string that corresponds?

E.g., Group4_Overall == '2.261667, which corresponds to 'Generally Effective' in 'control.rating.tbl'. It would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 8
      group   GOV  CORC  TMSC     AUDIT   PPS     TRAIN  Overall  Rating
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Group4  0.82   0.2 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.261667  Generally Effective
2 Group5  0.82   0.0 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.061667  Generally Effective
```

Comment: What if an overall score equal to something like 3.505?

Comment: Good catch. I think that's just an error in how I typed the ranges.

Comment: Updated table to reflect no gaps

Comment: I don't understand why the updated table means "no gaps". 2.9995, for example, has no associated Rating.

Comment: Sorry I updated it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can consider to use `case_when` from the `dplyr`. Notice that I changed the range of your classification a little bit because there are gaps in your original classification. For example, 3.505 will have no any associated classes based on your original classification. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Rating = case_when(
    Overall > 3.5 & Overall <= 4.00  ~ "Ineffective",
    Overall > 3 & Overall <= 3.5     ~ "Marginally Effective",
    Overall > 2.5 & Overall <= 3     ~ "Generally Effective",
    Overall >= 1 & Overall <= 2.5    ~ "Highly Effective"
  ))
```

Data:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "group   GOV  CORC  TMSC     AUDIT   PPS     TRAIN  Overall
1 Group4  0.82   0.2 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.261667
                 2 Group5  0.82   0.0 0.525 0.2833333   0.2 0.2333333 2.061667",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to approach it by referencing the table that was already created? Otherwise, this works quite nicely.

Comment: @Zach I am sure there is way to reference the table, but I am not familiar with those approaches. By the way, since you changed your `control.rating.tbl`, the ratings for your examples both are now `Generally Effective`.